# difference between numbers in sequence when ids missing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datediff, sequences

I'm trying to get the number of months between dates that have a DateOrderID to put them into an order(earliest date is one, second is 2 etc). My problem is that, because the DateOrder ID is entered manually I have some records where there is a missing DateOrderID so my query returns a NULL for that field. My (dummy) code is:

```
Select a.PersonID
,a.Date
,a.DateOrderID
,case when a.DateOrderID = 1 then 'First Date'
else convert(varchar(5),datediff(month, b.Date, a.Date)) end as Months_Between
from OrderTable a
left join
OrderTable b
on a.PersonID = b.PersonID and a.DateOrderID = b.DateOrderID +1
```

This currently returns

```
PersonID    Date     DateOrder  Months_Between
101         20150401    1       First Date
101         20160621    2       14
101         20170301    3       9
102         20110506    1       First Date
102         20140817    3       NULL
102         20160906    4       25
```

The result I want would replace the NULL for PersonID 102 with something like 'Missing ID'. I've tried a few things in the case statement but no success, any ideas?

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some product specifics there...

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Comment: Why wouldn't a simple ISNULL() around the CASE expression work?

Comment: It did - I was over complicating it by trying to calculate differences between ID numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.PersonID ,
  a.Date ,
  a.DateOrderID ,
  CASE
    WHEN a.DateOrderID = 1
    THEN 'First Date'
    ELSE ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEDIFF(MONTH, b.Date, a.Date)),'Missing Date')
  END AS Months_Between
FROM OrderTable a
LEFT JOIN OrderTable b
ON a.PersonID     = b.PersonID
AND a.DateOrderID = b.DateOrderID +1
```

Comment: Try to use ISNULL() function at your ELSE branch of CASE statement.

Comment: Perfect - again, trying complex things without thinking of the simple solutions. Many thanks!